# error:Algorithm negotiation fail with SharpSSH

Tags: c#, sharpssh, ssh.net

I have created a simple program running a connection and download from an SQL Server. To access the source of data i use an SSH with private/public keys.

Before it has worked fine but after updating SQL Server I got this error.

> error:Algorithm negotiation fail

Is this issue related to the update? I'm thinking on solving it using SSH.NET, instead of SharpSSH. In case this is the right solution, I have to re-write all the program, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not use [SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/sharpssh.aspx) it is not maintained from 2007. Most likely the new SQL Server does not support any of the KEX algorithms offered by old SharpSSH.

I believe your idea to switch to [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) is the right one.